# jsoup - How to extract this image using Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I'm looking for the main image which is in this div

```
<div id="imgTagWrapperId" >
<img src ="www.example.com">
</div>
```

I tried this :

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Elements img = document.select("div[id=imgTagWrapperId] img[src]");

String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
```

The URL i'm working with is http://www.amazon.in/Google-Nexus-D821-16GB-Black/dp/B00GC1J55C/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1421161258&sr=1-1&keywords=Google

This worked for me :

```
 Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

 Element img = document.getElementById("landingImage");

 String imgSrc = img.attr("data-old-hires");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Elements img = document.select("img[id=landingImage]");

String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me. I didn't find that id="landingImage" first.   This worked for me :  Document document =            Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Element img = document.getElementById("landingImage");

                String imgSrc = img.attr("data-old-hires");